# How does $\frac{3\sqrt{2x-1}-\frac{3x+4}{\sqrt{2x-1}}}{2x-1}$ simplify to $\frac{3x-7}{(2x-1)^{3/2}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, radicals

How does $$\frac{3\sqrt{2x-1}-\dfrac{3x+4}{\sqrt{2x-1}}}{2x-1}$$ simplify to $$\frac{3x-7}{(2x-1)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: Try multiplying the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{2x-1}$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cfrac {3\sqrt{2x-1}- \cfrac{(3x+4)}{\sqrt{2x-1}}} {2x-1}$

Take $LCM$ of the numerator term.

$\cfrac{\cfrac {3\sqrt{2x-1}(\sqrt{2x-1})- {(3x+4)}}{\sqrt{2x-1}}}{2x-1}$

You get:

$\cfrac{\cfrac {3(2x-1)- {(3x+4)}}{\sqrt{2x-1}}}{2x-1}$

$\cfrac {\cfrac{6x-3- 3x -4}{\sqrt{2x-1}}}{2x-1}$

$\cfrac {\cfrac {3x-7}{\sqrt{2x-1}}}{2x-1}$

And then, the powers add up, by the addition rule of exponents

so the final answer comes out to be :

${\cfrac {3x-7}{{(2x-1)^\frac{3}{2}}}}$

Comment: im actaully so stupid. I had done everything right except I forgot that I needed to make (3x+4) a negative and THEN add like terms together. Thank you